# WWW::Mechanize and Cookies

Tags: perl, cookies, mechanize, lwp

I use WWW::Mechanize::Shell to test stuff.
Since I didn't managed to sign in on a web site I want to scrape, I thought I will use the browser cookie (chrome or firefox) for that specific website with the 'cookie' command WWW::Mechanize::Shell has.

The question is, Cookies usually stored in a single file, which is not good, how to get a cookie for only this specific site?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why isn't storing cookies in a file good?

Since [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize) is built on top of [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/dist/LWP-UserAgent), you handle cookies just like you do in [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/dist/LWP-UserAgent). You can make the cookie jar a file or an in-memory hash.

If you don't want to save the cookies in a file, use an empty hash reference when you construct the mech object:

```
 use WWW::Mechanize;

 my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( cookie_jar => {} );
```

If you want to use a new file, make a new [HTTP::Cookies](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTTP-Cookies) object:

```
 use WWW::Mechanize;

 my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( 
     cookie_jar => HTTP::Cookies->new( file => "$ENV{HOME}/.cookies.txt" ) 
     );
```

If you want to load a browser specific cookies file, use the right module for it:

```
 use WWW::Mechanize;

 my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( 
     cookie_jar => HTTP::Cookies::Netscape->new( file => $filename ) 
     );
```

If you want no cookies at all, use undef explicitly:

```
 use WWW::Mechanize;

 my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( cookie_jar => undef );
```

All of this is in the docs.

Comment: Thats a good explanation, and was really helpful.
But, actually what I want is to LOAD cookies that I already have, the cookies are in the firefox cookies file (no idea where is it...).

Is it possible?

Comment: Well, use one of the HTTP::Cookie::* modules to handle the type of cookies file that you want to load.

Answer (score 5):

[`HTTP::Cookies::Netscape`](http://p3rl.org/HTTP::Cookies::Netscape), [`HTTP::Cookies::Microsoft`](http://p3rl.org/HTTP::Cookies::Microsoft) load your existing browser cookies.